# Simple Palindrome Issue

Tags: java

I am an amateur trying to learn programming.

I am trying to do a palindrome. However, I'm having an error in the code.

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String pal = "abc";

    public static void check(String pal)
    {
        if(pal==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Null Value..Exit");
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder(pal);
            str.reverse();
            System.out.println(str.reverse());
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong? Sorry I'm very new to programming. Just trying to learn!

Comment: You can't nest functions in Java.

Comment: First, before you write any code, stop and think exactly what the program should do. What steps should it do? What should the result be? How should it be structured? Have a plan before you start writing code.

Comment: When you have an error, the first thing to do is to read it, because the message indicates what is wrong and where. If you don't understand it, then post it, because we're not extra-lucid wizards, and error messages also help us.

Comment: @WilliamGaul: I think you meant `methods in Java`.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav If you want to be pedantic about it then yes, I meant methods.

Comment: `methods` not `functions` what they officially call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the below changes in your code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String pal = "abc";
    check(pal); // Nested methods are not allowed, thus calling the check
                // method, which is now placed outside main
}

public static void check(String pal) {
    if (pal == null) {
        System.out.println("Null Value..Exit");
    } else {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(pal);

        // I think I confused you by doing the below.
        // str = str.reverse(); // commenting this

        str.reverse(); // adding this 
        // str.reverse(); reverse will affect the str object. I just assigned it back to make it easier for you
        // That's why if you add a SOP with str.reverse, it'll reverse the string again, which will give the original string back
        // Original string will always be equal to itself. that's why your if will always be true
        // give a SOP with str.toString, not reverse.

        // str.toString is used because str is a StringBuilder object and not a String object.
        if (pal.equals(str.toString())) { // if the string and its reverse are equal, then its a palindrome
            System.out.println("Palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow. This is as detailed as it gets!

Can you suggest me a good place to learn java basics?

Comment: @RockyBalBoa - Here you go. [Java basics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/).

Comment: @RockyBalBoa -  I'd also suggest that you start using an IDE. It'll help you fix petty syntax errors and avoid of compilation issues. For logical problems, you can always come back here :)

Comment: At that moment, you won't be able to see the change. Try to add a sysout after `str = str.reverse();` and place a breakpoint at this place. I'm sure you'll be able to see the change.

Comment: Also, I have a question. I tried to put SOP after str = str.reverse(); Like this

str = str.reverse();
System.out.println(str.reverse());
if(pal.equals(str.toString()))

and I always get "it's a palindrome" and when I remove SOP (comment it), I get the actual answer. My question is: why is SOP affecting if(pal.equals(str.toString())) loop?

Comment: @RockyBalBoa - Check my answer now. I updated it for you to explain why you shouldn't use `str.reverse()` in SOP.

Answer (score 2):

you can not write one method inside another method.

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String pal = "abc";
check(pal);

    }
    public static void check(String pal)
    {
        if(pal==null)
        {
            System.out.println("Null Value..Exit");
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder(pal);
            str.reverse();
            System.out.println(str.reverse());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @javaBeginner given this you should have added the function call as `check(pal);` as well

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return false;
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
    strBuilder.reverse();
    return strBuilder.toString().equals(str);
}
```

You should probably do this.